# Join same field multiple times in table

Tags: mysql

I have this 2 tables and I am trying to join both of them multiple times but failed. Below are the tables.

Table ccaSubjects:

```html
+------------+----------+
| ccaSubject | ccaPrice |
+------------+----------+
| Chess      |      100 |
| Badminton  |      300 |
| Dancing    |      200 |
| Singing    |      200 |
| Football   |      250 |
| Fitness    |      600 |
| Robotics   |     1000 |
+------------+----------+
```

Table rispEnrollment

```html
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| studentIdentifier  | firstCCA  | secondCCA | thirdCCA |
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| elly@example.com   | Robotics  | Singing   | Dancing  |
| mike@example.com   | Chess     | Singing   | Robotics |
| tom@example.com    | Badminton | Dancing   | Chess    |
| peter@example.com  | Football  | Fitness   | Robotics |
| andrew@example.com | Robotics  | Singing   | Chess    |
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

I would like my output to be like:

```html
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| studentIdentifier  | firstCCA  | secondCCA | thirdCCA | CCA1price | CCA2price | CCA3price |
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| elly@example.com   | Robotics  | Singing   | Dancing  |      1000 |       200 |       200 |
| mike@example.com   | Chess     | Singing   | Robotics |       100 |       200 |      1000 |
| tom@example.com    | Badminton | Dancing   | Chess    |       300 |       200 |       100 |
| peter@example.com  | Football  | Fitness   | Robotics |       250 |       600 |      1000 |
| andrew@example.com | Robotics  | Singing   | Chess    |      1000 |       200 |       100 |
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

From my code, I am only able to use an inner join one time and get the `CCA1price`, and I cannot get `cca2price` and `cca3price` anymore because the error keeps saying `Same aliases`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may join the `rispEnrollment` table to the `ccaSubjects` table as many times as you need.  In this case, you may join three times to bring in the price columns for each of the three subject columns.

```
SELECT
    t1.studentIdentifier,
    t1.firstCCA,
    t1.secondCCA,
    t1.thirdCCA,
    t2.ccaPrice AS CCA1price,
    t3.ccaPrice AS CCA2price,
    t4.ccaPrice AS CCA3price
FROM rispEnrollment t1
LEFT JOIN ccaSubjects t2
    ON t1.firstCCA = t2.ccaSubject
LEFT JOIN ccaSubjects t3
    ON t1.secondCCA = t3.ccaSubject
LEFT JOIN ccaSubjects t4
    ON t1.thirdCCA = t4.ccaSubject;
```

Note that I use left joins here just in case the `rispEnrollment` table might have a subject which does not match to anything in the `ccaSubjects` table.